# AngularJS: Directive repetition, works as attribute but not as element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I write twice the same directive as attribute, I get twice the result, but when I write it twice as element, I only get the result once, why?

I have a very simple directive:

```
.directive("ngMyText", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE'
      };
})
```

An `$scope` with a collection of items:

```
$scope.items = [
    { text:"AAA", show:true },
    { text:"BBB", show:true }
];
```

Therefore, when doing this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="container">
        <div data-ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" ng-bind="item.text"></div>
        <div data-ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" ng-bind="item.text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" ng-bind="item.text" />
        <ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" ng-bind="item.text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect to get the collection rendered twice in each container, but in the second container only happens once. Why does this happen?

I have created an runable example with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/mzAPk/

Cheers.

Comment: It works if you don't use the XML-style self-closing tag (i.e. change it to `<ng-my-text ...></ng-my-text>`)

Comment: Right right :D Do you want to put that as answer and I will mark it?

Comment: @DanielBeck is right. You're probably in HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/2057033. Don't use the `<foo />` syntax, except for the void elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) This

```
<ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" 
ng-bind="item.text" />
```

should be

```
<ng-my-text ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{show:true}" 
ng-bind="item.text"></ng-my-text>
```